# Does "default" constructor mean "default parameters" or "provided by C++"?

Tags: c++

I'm confused on what "default constructors" are because I'm getting two meanings from both my class and also online.

1) We have written a constructor ourselves, but we made the parameters set to default values.

2) We have NOT written ANY construct at all, but we can still "pretend" like we did and initialize an instance of a class using a C++ "provided constructor"

If the case is #2, what happens when you initialize? Garbage values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[[class.ctor]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#4):

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X`
>   for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a
>   default argument (including the case of a constructor with no
>   parameters). If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a
>   non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted ([dcl.fct.def]). An implicitly-declared default
>   constructor is an `inline public` member of its class.

If you do not provide any constructors, then C++ will synthesize a (possibly deleted) default constructor.  The semantics of this synthesized constructor is specified in [[class.ctor]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#7):

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is
>   *implicitly defined* when it is odr-used to create an object of its class type ([intro.object]) or when it is explicitly defaulted after
>   its first declaration. **The implicitly-defined default constructor
>   performs the set of initializations of the class that would be
>   performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no
>   *ctor-initializer* and an empty *compound-statement*.** If that user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed. If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the
>   requirements of a constexpr constructor, the implicitly-defined
>   default constructor is `constexpr`. Before the defaulted default
>   constructor for a class is implicitly defined, all the
>   non-user-provided default constructors for its base classes and its
>   non-static data members shall have been implicitly defined.
>   [ *Note:* An implicitly-declared default constructor has an
>   exception specification ([except.spec]). An explicitly-defaulted
>   definition might have an implicit exception specification, see
>   [dcl.fct.def]. — *end note* ]

Therefore, yes, the data members will be default initialized without an in-class member initializers.  This leaves members of builtin types uninitialized.

Comment: So if I have a struct posn, for example, that just takes an int x, and int y, if I don't provide any constructors at all, C++ will make one for me... and x and y will be initialized to... 0?
That's what it did when I test it...

Comment: @ming Please edit your question to include a [mre].  Your description isn't enough to uniquely identify the result.

Comment: @ming default initialization of  `int` type leaves the value uninitialized (so might be 0, might not...), except static and global variables are 0.